# I need to store 0 or 1 to .status file in server php

Tags: javascript, php, html, raspberry-pi

I need to create 2 radio buttons and check one of them based on .status file content (o or 1)
And I have to store that value in server file upon change of radio button checked. I tried this way, but failed. radio buttons are created as expected but the au() and ma() functions are executing. Need help..!

Is there any simplest way to do this. As I also have to write some php code in that function, so that I can send o or 1 to my Raspberry Pi GPIO.

Thanks in advance.

```html
  <?php
        $status = 0;
        $status = file_get_contents('/home/pi/.status');
        echo $status;
        echo "</br>"; ?>

        <?php if ( $status == 0 ) {  ?>

                <input onchange="<?php au(); ?>" id="auto" type="radio" name="set" value="auto" checked> Auto<br>
                <input onchange="<?php ma(); ?>" id="manual" type="radio" name="set" value="manula"> Manual<br><br>

        <?php } elseif ( $status == 1 ) {  ?>

                <input onchange="<?php au(); ?>" id="auto" type="radio" name="set" value="auto" > Auto<br>
                <input onchange="<?php ma(); ?>" id="manual" type="radio" name="set" value="manula" checked> Manual<br><br>

        <?php }
        function au()
        {
                echo 1 > /home/pi/.status;
        };
        function ma()
        {
                echo 0 > /home/pi/.status;
        };
        ?>
```

Comment: The ```onchange``` event handler is used to call a JavaScript function not a PHP function.  You will either need to submit the form back to PHP or you will need to use AJAX to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite just like that. If you want to write on a file (.status) dynamically (without the page's refresh), you need to code this with JavaScript.

However, JavaSrcipt does not allow you to edit file. So you need to take an other point of view.

Create a PHP form to choose if you want that your code write *0* or *1* to *.status* file:

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="GET">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="automatic" value="auto"> Automatique</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
```

Then, in the page which handles the form, insert:

```
$fp = fopen('/home/pi/.status', 'w'); // It replaces content to what you will write now
if($fp != false)
{
   if (isset($_GET['automatic']) && $_GET['automatic'] == 'auto')
   {
      fwrite($fp, '1');
   }
   else
   {
      fwrite($fp, '1');
   }
   fclose($fp);
}
```

If you want more information about file handling, take a look to [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) PHP documentation.

Hope it helps you!

**Note**: I deliberately avoid to talk about AJAX and Web Service (WS) because a post is not enough to explain.